# update error in wcf service application

Tags: database, wcf

I'm getting this error while updating a row in my database.

> An exception of type 'System.Data.OleDb.OleDbException' occurred in System.Data.dll but was not handled in user code
>
> Additional information: Syntax error in UPDATE statement.
>
> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

This is my update code:

```
public string UpdateInventory(string name, int quantity)
{
        string strMessage = string.Empty;
        string sql;

        //Create connection object
        OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString);
        oleConn.Open();

        //Update a row
        sql = "UPDATE Product SET Quantity Attribute = '" + quantity + "' WHERE Name = '" + name + "'";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);

        int rowsAffected = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if(rowsAffected > 0)
        {
            strMessage = name + "Details updated succesfully";
        }
        else
        {
            strMessage = name + "Details not updated successfully";
        }

        oleConn.Close();

        return strMessage;
}
```

But if I update the decimal price and string description with the same codes. it goes well. It just getting that codes when updating the quantity.

Comment: [SQL Injection alert](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms161953%28v=sql.105%29.aspx) - you should **not** concatenate together your SQL statements - use **parametrized queries** instead to avoid SQL injection

Comment: Use brackets around `Quantity Attribute` to handle the space - `UPDATE Product SET [Quantity Attribute]` to fix the most likely reason for the syntax error.  And while you're at, do as @marc_s said and change your code to use parameterized queries.

Answer (score 0):

Your column name `Quantity Attribute` has a space in it, which is most likely causing the syntax error.  You can use brackets around the column name to resolve this.  Also, `quantity` is an `int`, and you're trying to use it as a string in the SQL command.  Most likely it's also an `int` in the table, so you don't need `'` around that value either, but without knowing your table's schema that's just a guess.

The biggest problem with your code is that it is vulnerable to SQL Injection attacks.  You can guard against that by using parameterized queries.  Parameterized queries have an added benefit of handling any required quoting of the values for you, based on the type of the individual parameters.

Finally it's considered best practice to use a `using` block for the connection, which will take care of closing and disposing the connection for you when the `using` block is exited, even if an error occurs.

Here's an example that wraps all of this up:

```
try
{
    using (OleDbConnection oleConn = new OleDbConnection(connString))
    {
        oleConn.Open();

        //Update a row
        sql = "UPDATE Product SET [Quantity Attribute] = ? WHERE Name = ?";

        OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(sql, oleConn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Quantity", OleDbType.Int).Value = quantity;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@Name", OleDbType.VarChar).Value = name;

        int rowsAffected = (int)cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();

        if(rowsAffected > 0)
        {
            strMessage = name + "Details updated succesfully";
        }
        else
        {
            strMessage = name + "Details not updated successfully";
        }
    }
}
catch (Exception ex)
{
    strMessage = String.Format("Update error: {0}", ex.Message);
}
```

Note that for OleDb a question mark is used as a placeholder for the parameters, so the order in which you add the parameters is important - they must match the order of the placeholders in the query string.

The resulting SQL would look like this (assuming Quantity Attribute is an int, and `quantity` = 20 and `name` = "Sample":

```
UPDATE Product SET [Quantity Attribute] = 20 WHERE Name = 'Sample'
```

As a final recommendation I also wrapped the code in a try-catch block so if an exception is thrown it would be caught and handled.  Unhandled exceptions can also reveal information about your program that shouldn't be revealed (as it can give potential hackers more information to refine their attempts to compromise your system).  Since this is a WCF service, depending on your configuration exception details may or may not be returned to the client, but an unhandled exception can bring your service down and will fault the client's channel to the service.